# Issues pulling value of cell using excel com objects in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, loops, com

I am writing a script that scans each cell in an excel file for PII. I've got most of it working, but I am experiencing two issues which may be related.

First of all, I am not convinced that the "Do" loop is performing as intended. The goal here is if the text in a cell matches the regex string, create a PSCustomObject with the location information, then use the object to add a line to a csv file.

It appears that the loop is running for every file, regardless of whether or not it actually found a match.

The other issue is that I can't seem to actually pull the cell value for the matched cell. I've tried several different variables and methods, the latest attempt being "$target.text," but the value of the variable is always null.

I've been racking my brain on this for days, but I'm sure it'll be obvious once I see it.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
$searchtext = "\b(?!0{3}|6{3})([0-6]\d{2}|7([0-6]\d|7[012]))([ -]?)(?!00)\d\d\3(?!0000)\d{4}\b"
$xlsFiles = Get-ChildItem $searchpath -recurse -include *.xlsx, *.xls, *.xlxm | Select-object -Expand FullName
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false;
$excel.AskToUpdateLinks = $false;
foreach ($xlsfile in $xlsfiles) {
Write-host (Get-Date -f yyyymmdd:hhmm) $xlsfile
try{
      $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($xlsFile, 0, 0, 5, "password")
     }
Catch {
    Write-host $xlsfile 'is password protected. Skipping...' -ForegroundColor Yellow
    continue
} 

ForEach ($Sheet in $($Workbook.Sheets)) {
            $i = $sheet.Index
            $Range = $Workbook.Sheets.Item($i).UsedRange
            $Target = $Sheet.UsedRange.Find($Searchtext)
            $First = $Target
            Do {
                  $Target = $Range.Find($Target)
                  $Violation = [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Path       = $xlsfile
                        Line       = "SSN Found" + $target.text
                        LineNumber = "Sheet: " + $i
                  }
                  $Violation | Select-Object Path, Line, LineNumber | export-csv $outputpath\$PIIFile -append -NoTypeInformation
            }
            While ($NULL -ne $Target -and $Target.AddressLocal() -ne $First.AddressLocal())
      }
      $Excel.Quit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just a simple case of faulty logic in the loops.
Thanks to everyone who looked at this.